# Don't allow screen to fade

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, screen

Is it possible for an iOS app to disable fading the iPad/iPod screen when there hasn’t been user interaction for a longer period of time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, look at the idleTimerDisabled property on UIApplication

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html